# Activate an on-screen keyboard in KDE

Tags: kubuntu, 19.04

How do I start an on-screen display on my laptop with touchscreen?

I tried florence:

```
 sudo apt install florence
```

But that seems quite old-scool and is always on top. Not usable!

How do I get an on-screen display like in Ubuntu unity?

Answer (score 15):

OnBoard is a good virtual keyboard not especially for KDE, but working on most Linux:

```
 sudo apt install onboard
```

Automatic opening and closing won't work on KDE but it places a status icon in the tray area which will let it pop up when clicked.