# On-screen keyboard for Kubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, software-recommendation, kde, accessibility

It seems that the only available option is `matchbox-keyboard`, but it's pretty useless without the ability to change the font size of the labels.

I'll nice for a change and not post my opinion of its author.

Answer (score 0):

Onboard is an option.
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/onboard.1.html,
https://launchpad.net/onboard,
https://askubuntu.com/a/1162219/226614.

If you have KDE, I think it comes with a built in on screen keyboard.